# How to send dropdown value to servlet NOT the option text

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have dropdown with options and the values. I can get the option value by the dropdown name in servlet but how can i get the dropdown "value" in servlet. In screenshot, temporarily i concatenated the with options but i want to store value in variable in servlet.
Please help:

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" name="taxiDropdown" id= "taxiDropdown" placeholder="Search taxi...">
                            </div>
                                <div class="scrolling menu">
                                    <%
                                        List eList = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("taxiInfo");
                                    %>
                                    <%
                                        for (int i = 0; i < eList.size(); i++) {
                                    %>
                                    <div class="item" data-value="<%=((TaxiInfo) eList.get(i)).getID()%>">
                                        <div class="ui green empty circular label"></div>
                                        <%=((TaxiInfo) eList.get(i)).getTaxiPlate() +" "+ ((TaxiInfo) eList.get(i)).getID() %>

                                    </div>
                                    <%
                                        }
                                    %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Servlet:

```
String val = request.getParameter("taxiDropdown");
```

(in "val", I want to store the value of the dropdown not the option text)

[image]

Comment: do you need `(TaxiInfo) eList.get(i)).getID()` value ? Also what does `val` gives you ?

Comment: Absolutely right, how can i get that? so dropdown option giving me 1076(name in table) and value give me (1(ID in table)

Comment: when you select any option from dropdown what does `String val = request.getParameter("taxiDropdown")` val gives you in servlet ? both values ? or only one ?

Comment: Thanks, another person said, i couldn't get the "Value"(input name="text" value="123") without putting in html. As you see in brackets, i am trying to get "123" with getParameter which is not possible i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSP you should have something like that:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="taxiDropdown" id="taxiDropdown">
        <%
            List<TaxiInfo> eList = (List<TaxiInfo>) request.getAttribute("taxiInfo");
            for (TaxiInfo taxiInfo : eList) {
        %>
        <option name="<%=taxiInfo.getTaxiPlate()%>" value="<%=taxiInfo.getID()%>"><%=taxiInfo.getTaxiPlate()%></option>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in controller/servlet you will receive the id of TaxiInfo:

```
String val = request.getParameter("taxiDropdown");
System.out.println(val);
```

Or in your case you should set a hidden input with javascript with desired value.

Comment: so you saying, there is no way to get value="<%=taxiInfo.getID()%>">               in request.getParameter without hidden input?

Comment: Yes, as I know, you can't get the value of taxiInfo.ID without using a classic html select, or with a hidden input that you set with javascript.

Comment: Good to know, i added hidden field and get the value. thank you

Answer (score 0):

added this code in html:

Move value of the dropdown selection to hidden textbox

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('#driverdp').change(function() { <-- this is my dropdown -->
            var x = $(this).val();
            $('#driverid').val(x); <-- this is my textbox -->
        });
    });
</script>
```

Servlet:
get the value of hidden text in servlet

```
String text= request.getParameter("driverId");
```

hope it will help someone